# Create a table in postgreSQL using Node-red

Tags: node-red

I wanted to create a table and insert data from a CSV file in Node-red postgreSQL. Is there any possibility to do it like PG Create?
script I used [script to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jymAy.jpg) message shown in the debug as [Debug message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHRDt.jpg)

Thanks in Advance

Update: Using msg.payload instead of msg.topic it worked which solved my problem

Comment: Please provide more info

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I want to import CSV to different databses, I'm able to create a table in MySQL. I also loaded data in both MySQL and MongoDB in Node-RED. I have tried with [node-red postgres suite](https://github.com/redconnect-io/node-red-contrib-postgres) library also. But, couldn't create. I''m passing the query to payload.

Answer (score 0):

Using msg.payload instead of msg.topic it worked which solved my problem

removing template node and connecting function directly to postgres node

In the function node I wrote
msg.payload = "CREATE TABLE ...";